# How to correctly redirect with nginx?

Tags: xml, nginx

When user goes to `mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml`, I want the browser to display the file in `mywebsite.com/static/sitemap.xml` (The browser URL is still `mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml`)

This is my nginx setup and it does not work. When I go to `mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml` it says `404 Not Found`. I can access `mywebsite.com/static/sitemap.xml`.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;


    location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    
    
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    
    
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    
    
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    }

    location /sitemap.xml {
        alias /static/sitemap.xml;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/sitemap\.xml$ /static/sitemap.xml last;`

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. If you make it an answer I will accept

Comment: @VII The `alias` way should work too, but you should use full path from the server root folder, i.e. `alias /var/www/mywebsite/static/sitemap.xml;`. But for this particular case it is better to use `root` directive: `root /var/www/mywebsite/static;`.